# How do we know if god is angry on someone?

Tags: gods

What scriptures mention about when god is angry on anyone?

Will he be angry if we wont give much attention to him?

I rarely went to Ganesh mandap during these 9 days Ganesh utsav, will he be angry on me?

I am not asking this in my own context but generally when god will get angry on anyone?

I immediately get consequences when it comes to Lord Ganesha only if I did not worship him properly and will see all problems one by one continuously.

Problems means not allowig to eat his prasad or creating problems to do his puja etc.

Comment: God is Love. Love is God. God is never angry with anyone.

Comment: There is some theft happened in a temple near my place, but God punished them after few days. Is it not because of his angry?